# How to align some text as right aligned in textarea?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have some text(which contains some Arabic also) saved in DB. I am fetching the data and displaying them in the textarea.

[image]

**I want the English text to be aligned left, and the arabic text to be aligned right.**

For this, I have split the whole text into paragraphs and detect which paragraph should be right aligned and which one should be left aligned.

Here's the code.

```
/*------ Allign text ------*/
function align_text($text)
{
    $string = $text;
    $returnString = '';
    $paraArray = explode("\n", $string);
    if(count($paraArray) > 0)
    {
        foreach($paraArray as $pa)
        {
            $isRight = $this->is_rtl($pa);
            if($isRight)
            {
                $para['para'] = $pa;
                $para['align'] = 'R';
            }
            else
            {
                $para['para'] = $pa;
                $para['align'] = 'L';
            }
            $paraArr[] = $para;
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }
    return $paraArr;
}

function is_rtl($string) 
{
    $rtl_chars_pattern = '/[\x{0590}-\x{05ff}\x{0600}-\x{06ff}]/u';
    return preg_match($rtl_chars_pattern, $string);
}
```

So, as you can see, each paragraph can be arranged as per Right-aligned and Left-aligned when displaying in webpage(html) using div.

```
<?php
foreach($paraArr as $row)
{
   if($row['align'] == 'L')
   {?>
    <div class="left-align"><?php echo $row['para'];?></div>
   <?php
   }
   else
   {?>
   <div class="left-align"><?php echo $row['para'];?></div>
  <?php }
}?>
```

But my main question is, **How can I align the Arabic paragraph as right aligned inside SAME textarea?**.

Comment: Arabic text is only displayed when user looks at webpage in arabic? Can't you do something like if(english) { div class = "english" } Actually duplicating your code but when user selects arabic second styling class will come into play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it (showing both left- and right-aligned text) in one textarea. Instead, You can show them as divs and use the `contentEditable` to make them editable. Each div may have its own alignment (left or right).

For example, you may declare a parent div containing a child div per paragraph:

```
<div>
      <div contenteditable="true">
             Paragraph one
      </div>

      <div contenteditable="true">
             Paragraph 2
      </div>
</div>
```

Each div may be styled to be left-to-right or right-to-left independently. It becomes editable whenever the user clicks on it.

You can also use some third-party HTML editor instead of the textarea. Here are some examples (google them): TinyMCE, Scribe, jHTMLArea, CKEditor, Nicedit, ...

Comment: can you explain this approach?